# java.net.SocketTimeoutException while uploading a long encoded string to server in android

Tags: java, android, http

I am using httpok library for network requests. The code is working fine if i send only ID,Name,age etc
 but when i send the "encodedPhotoString" which is 
a long string of the image to be uplaoded to server and is about 8000 characters the code is throwing java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
Exception. I have tried to change the connect timeout and read timeout but that's not working for me. I am using namecheap.com hosting server.
Please help me with this issue. Thank you.

```
 public class AddUserAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    OkHttpClient client=null;
    RequestBody formBody=null;
    Request request=null;
    JSONObject json = null;
    String fromServer = "";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadImage.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        GetUserDetails();
        GenerateGCMID();
        email= email.trim().toLowerCase();
        latitude = GPSTracker.getLatitude();
        longitude =  GPSTracker.getLongitude(); 
        client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().readTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("ID",ID)
                .add("Name",name)
                .add("email",email)
                .add("password",password)
                .add("age",age)
                .add("number",number)
                .add("bloodgroup",bloodgroup)
                .add("lat",latitude+"")
                .add("longi",longitude+"")
                .add("image",encodedPhotoString)
                .build();
        request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://faceblood.website/blood_app/Adduser.php")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String res = response.body().string();
            json = new JSONObject(res);
            fromServer = json.getString("added");
            Log.e("stringtest",json.getString("added"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONException",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        pDialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("fromServer",fromServer);
        if(fromServer.equals("addeduser")){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            onSignupSuccess();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Network problem. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<?php
require "conn.php";

$id = $_POST["ID"];

$name = $_POST["Name"];

$email = $_POST["email"];

$password = $_POST["password"];

$age = $_POST["age"];

$number = $_POST["number"];

$blood = $_POST["bloodgroup"];

$latitude = $_POST["lat"];

$longitude = $_POST["longi"];

$image = $_POST["image"];

$splitEmail = explode('@', $email);
$imageValue = base64_decode($image);
$image = $splitEmail[0].".jpg";
$path = "images/".$image;
file_put_contents($path, $imageValue);


$sql = "INSERT INTO UserDetails (ID,Name,email,password,age,number,bloodgroup,lat,longi,image)
VALUES ('$id','$name','$email','$password','$age','$number','$blood','$latitude','$longitude','$image')"; 
 


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $response["added"] = "addeduser";
} else {

}

echo json_encode($response); 
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: 8000 characters is not long.  The problem is because of something in your network, you're not actually hitting your server, or the server isn't responding.  I'd debug your server side.

Comment: Its not server problem i guess because without uploading the photostring every time i tried the data is stored successfully. Moreover my code on server side is also tested. For more clarity i am upload that code as well.

Comment: @GabeSechan u can see the server side code as well. Updated.

Comment: I'd look at your server logs anyway-  did the device actually hit the server?  Did it complete its processing?  Did the server throw an error because the client misformatted something?  By debugging the server you can help figure out where in the process the client screws up.

Comment: i am beginner to android...please guide me how can i get server logs ? @GabeSechan

Comment: That's not an android thing, its a server side thing.  And that depends on what web server you're using, your configuration, and what OS you're on.  Google can help you better than I can

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set writeTimeout

```
client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().readTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()
```